# How to write a where condition in laravel query?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I write one query which will return true or false by using exists() function in laravel like this

```
$a=$item->conditions()->exists();
```

The above query works fine ,now i want to extend the query with `where` condition that will check weather the `status column should equal to the active` for that i am writing the following code but it's throwing an error like `Call to a member function where() on boolean` ,please help me to extend the query for writing a where condition.

```
$a=$item->conditions()->exists()->where('status','=','active');
```

Note:-
conditions() -->returns an ID from the model

Comment: Use `$item->conditions()->where('status', 'active')->exists();`

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to write the where condition before call `exists()` method.
So it's gonna be like this:

```
$a = $item->conditions()->where('status','=','active')->exists();
```

Comment: i have one more doubt it will check both the id and status na in condition table , that means it won't effect previous my query ryt..?

Comment: Hmm, idk what's in your `condition()` but you writing all condition in a same statement so the answer is no. It will effect your previous query.